# Running iOS SDK built in arm7 on arm7s

Tags: ios, xcode, legacy, arm7

I have an SDK to achieve some special stream of video but I've got only the binary of this, I think this was built for arm7.
I have an app built with this library and it runs great on iPhone 4, 4s and iPad 2 but when building for iPad 4th generation with an arm7s xcode shows lots of errors about files being ignored.
I'm pretty sure it's the architecture cause changing the build architecture the errors appear and disappear.
Is there any way to make this work? I mean build for new architectures having only binaries files of the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not. To build your app for armv7s all the code – which includes said library – has to be built for it. There is a [hack](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/) to add armv7s support to static libraries but I would strongly recommend against using it.

That being said, for now it's not a big deal if you're building your app for armv7 only. It will still work fine on the iPhone 5.

Just go into the build settings of your Target and set "armv7" as the only architecture your app should be built for.

At one point in the future Apple will probably require that all new apps / app updates will be built for armv7s, like the did with armv7 a few years ago, but for now it's not a problem. By then the developer of the static library will hopefully have provided an update.

Comment: Thanks, building only for arm7 works fine (I also had to set the `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO) guess I only have left to hope a new arm7s release of this libraries.

Comment: @MarkE - Good point.  Setting the `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO is ideal for distribution.  I had major problems transitioning to iPhone 5, and this turned out to be my problem.